# Aborting Script and Allowing Normal Behavior to Occur

Tags: filemaker

If a field is configured so that clicking on it runs a script, is there a way from within the script to abort/cancel and allow the field's normal click behavior to occur?

Example: Suppose I have a container field which triggers a script when the field is clicked. Based on logic in the script, sometimes an Insert File dialog should be displayed. Other times, the script should stop running and the field should behave as though it hadn't triggered a script--that is, the normal Record Audio dialog or right-click pop-up menu should be displayed. How would I go about doing this?

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a script trigger OnObjectEnter as this allows the contextual menu. If you set a button on the field the contextual menu will not be displayed and there is no way to get it to appear thru scripting.

The script trigger for OnObjectEnter will also get called AFTER the user selects one of the import options (or if they don't select any option) but it also gets called if the user directly clicks on the field.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, @andyknas. Unfortunately, OnObjectEnter is only triggered when the object is entered, not each time it is clicked on. The first time I click on the object (assuming that the object wasn't selected by default), OnObjectEnter is called. However, if I click again on the object, the script is not called and FMP's default behavior occurs because the object has not been re-entered. So, this approach only partially allows me to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Correct. The only way to trap every click would be to use a button script, but then you loose the contextual menu.

Answer (score 0):

This script (screenshot below) should solve your problem. Let me know if it doesn't.

[image: Screenshot of script that does what you want]

Comment: Are you associating this script with the field via button setup (with settings like Perform Script, Pause Current Script)?